# Is this the correct way to vent my roof?

Tags: roof, vent, product-recommendation

We recently bought a 1950s vintage house with no soffits, i.e. no roof overhang. Thus there are no soffit vents in my attic, only a ridge vent and 2 gable vents, one with a powered fan. However, those are only outtakes, and as far as I know, the only fresh air is coming in from the door to the attic (this is a split-level).

I believe we need some sort of intake venting in the roof, and my roofer recommended an [on-roof vent product](http://www.cor-a-vent.com/blog/index.cfm?p=11).

Has anyone had experience with this type of product? Specifically:

- Does it provide adequate air flow?
- Are there water/ice penetration issues?
- Are there other options for a house with no soffits?

Comment: You asked this question almost two years ago.  Did you ever find an answer anywhere?  I have the exact same situation and when I found your question, I was hoping I had found an answer, too. But, alas, not yet.

Comment: No, I ended up getting three retrofitted 6" vents installed equidistant from each other. It seems to help with airflow.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the links have changed, but if this is the product that you were looking at...

[image]

then yes, I have had experience with roof to wall vents... they work; but they are for the tops of roofs, where they meet a wall (like for an addition on the side of a house). So, I don't think it would be useful for your house, if I understand your question correctly. If you installed soffits (or found a way to vent without them), then you may want to use a ridge vent (kind of the same thing), but I don't really understand a way around adding/building an overhang in order to have soffits.

I would like to see a pic of your way/solution around soffits (6" vents installed equidistant from each other).

[image][image]